# C# Unity Raycast problems, camera not responding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I created a raycast between my player and the camera that, when it detects a hit, moves the camera in front of the object so that the object does not obstruct the view.

A debug test shows that the raycast is certainly working. However the only message I get from the console concerning my code is that the variable targetMoveUse is assigned but its value is never used.

I learned this code from a tutorial on youtube and followed it to a tee but despite having what appears to be identical code to the tutorial, it's not working for me. The tutorial is here for reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0nI0rX5fEY0

And here's my code. Any help is appreciated.

```
Transform player;
Quaternion targetLook;
Vector3 targetMove;
public float rayHitMoveInFront = 0.1f;
Vector3 targetMoveUse;
public float smoothLook = 0.5f;
public float smoothMove = 0.5f;
Vector3 smoothMoveV;
public float distFromPlayer = 5;
public float heightFromPlayer = 3;

void Start () {
    player = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player").transform;
}

void Update () {
    targetMove = player.position + (player.rotation * new Vector3 (0, heightFromPlayer, -distFromPlayer));

    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast (player.position, targetMove - player.position, out hit, Vector3.Distance (player.position, targetMove)))
        targetMoveUse = Vector3.Lerp (hit.point, player.position, rayHitMoveInFront);
    else 
        targetMoveUse = targetMove;

    //chapter 4 episode 3 part 1
    //transform.position = player.position + (player.rotation * new Vector3 (0, heightFromPlayer, -distFromPlayer));


    //transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, targetMove, smoothMove * Time.deltaTime);

    transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp (transform.position, targetMove, ref smoothMoveV, smoothMove);

    targetLook = Quaternion.LookRotation (player.position - transform.position);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (transform.rotation, targetLook, smoothLook * Time.deltaTime);
    //chapter 4 episode 1
    //transform.LookAt (player);
}
```

}

Comment: So what's not working? You didn't mention that part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this line,

```
  transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp (transform.position, targetMove, ref smoothMoveV, smoothMove);
```

replace targetMove variable with targetMoveUse

```
transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp (transform.position, targetMoveUse, ref smoothMoveV, smoothMove);
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome, Please tick this post as the correct answer.